# JSF Composite Component, change event on targeted element

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, composite-component

We have build the following component:

```
  <h:panelGroup id="#{cc.attrs.id}Component" rendered="#{cc.attrs.rendered}">
  <div id="#{cc.attrs.id}" class="select #{cc.attrs.styleClass}" >
    <h:inputText id="input" disabled="#{cc.attrs.disabled}"
      value="#{cc.attrs.value}"
      tabindex="#{cc.attrs.tabindex}" maxlength="#{cc.attrs.maxlength}" 
      converter="#{cc.attrs.converter}">
      <a4j:ajax event="change" render="select" />        
    </h:inputText>
    <rich:select disabled="#{cc.attrs.disabled}"
      id="select" value="#{cc.attrs.value}"
      listWidth="#{cc.attrs.listWidth}"
      converter="#{cc.attrs.converter}">          
      <f:selectItems value="#{cc.attrs.items}" var="si"
        itemValue="#{xyz}" itemLabel="#{xyz.name}" />
      <a4j:ajax event="selectitem" render="input" />           
    </rich:select>
    </div>        
  </h:panelGroup>
```

We have defined that we accept a change event with the targets input and select:

```
<composite:clientBehavior name="change" event="change" targets="input select"/>
```

However for the select Item we really need the event to be "selectItem" and not "change".

Obviously we could accept both "change" and "selectItem" in the interface, however this would mean that the the implementer would have to specify both change and selectItem actions.

```
<a4j:ajax event="change" ... />
<a4J:ajax event="selectItem" ... />
```

Is there any way we can change the event on the target input from change to selectItem?

Answer (score 0):

May be like this.

```
<composite:clientBehavior name="change" event="change" targets="input"/>
<composite:clientBehavior name="change" event="selectItem" targets="select"/>
```